# file_get_contents(http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Warning: file_get_contents(http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /home/content/93/11389393/html/white/bet_gg.php on line 286

```
$grabPrice = file_get_contents('http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast');
$data = json_decode($grabPrice);
$current_price = $data->data->last_local->value;
```

Comment: Is there something you want to get an explanation on?

Comment: You need to give more info.  The request works for me on `PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 28 2012 18:19:13)`

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your PHP settings?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in PHP
If not - use cURL to grab some page by URL - works great

Answer (score 0):

check if allow_url_fopen is enabled

```
phpinfo();
```

or

```
if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
  echo "Enable";
} else{
  echo "Not enable";
}
```

if no, in your php.ini change

```
allow_url_fopen =0;
```

to

```
allow_url_fopen =1;
```

Comment: Or you could use `phpinfo()` to display the current state of all of the php settings.